# Как сделать псевдоэлемент под родителем

Tags: html, css

псевдоэлемент не отображается под родителем.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyawxtq2/5/ вот пример на фидл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="hero__btn btn">
test
                    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.btn {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 142.4%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #AE0034;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;

}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(6.44deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У родителя нужно убрать z-index совсем, а псевдоэлементу задать отрицательное значение:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.btn {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 142.4%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #AE0034;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  position: relative;

}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(6.44deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="hero__btn btn">
test</button>
```